# SSRS % of total across columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to show the value of a summarized column as a percent of the whole. In the image attached, I would like to show the "Buy Out %" column as a % of the whole Extended Price for both "Buy Out" and "Stock".

For the 1st group "HOUMA LA" it would be 6,547,543.37/(6,547,543.37 + 2,647,444.26)

[image]

My design is as follows:
[image]

Here is a data snippit:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more info. Can you show your report design and a sample of the data in your datasets as both these will influence the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following expression in your `Buy Out %` texbox:

```
=Fields!ExtendedPrice.Value / (Fields!ExtendedPrice.Value + Fields!ExtendedPrice.Value)
```

Then go to the textbox properties and chose `Percentage` as the number format.

If the calculation should happen inside a group (for example your `Houma La`) then you have to add the scope to the fields:

```
=(Fields!ExtendedPrice.Value, "HoumaLaGroupName") / 
 ((Fields!ExtendedPrice.Value, "HoumaLaGroupName") + (Fields!ExtendedPrice.Value, "HoumaLaGroupName"))
```

**UPDATE**

You have two ways to go here.

1. You can reference to `extended price (Buy out)` and `extended price (Stock)` with the following expression, which you put into the textbox `Buy out %`. For this you have to use the name of the textbox, where `extended price (Buy out)` and `extended price (Stock)` are (this way you reference directly to the value in the textbox, which would be `6,547,543.37/(6,547,543.37 + 2,647,444.26)`):

   ```
   =ReportItems!ExtendedPriceBuyOutTextboxName.Value / (ReportItems!ExtendedPriceBuyOutTextboxName.Value + ReportItems!ExtendendPriceStockTextboxName.Value)
   ```
2. You use the expression from the `extended price (Buy out)` and `extended price (Stock)` textboxes again:

   ```
   =(ExpressionExtendedPriceBuyOut) / ((ExpressionExtendedPriceBuyOut) + (EypressionExtendendPriceStock
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your approach earlier, and it just gives me 50% for everything. Since they are part of the same column group name I can't specify group for the calculation. I tried: =(Fields!extended_price.Value, "source_status")/((Fields!extended_price.Value, "source_status") + (Fields!extended_price.Value, "source_status"))

Comment: I see, your `extended price (Buy out)` and `extended price (Stock)` are already totals. I will update my answer.

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you.